# What's the fastest way to find unique lines from huge file A as compared to huge file B using python?

Tags: python, compare

I got txt file A with 300, 000+ lines and txt file B with 600, 000+ lines. Now what I want to do is to sift through file A line by line, if that line does not appear in file B then it will be appended to file C.

Well, the problem is if I program like what I said above, it literally takes ages to finish all the job. So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html might be of use, which is almost certainly going to be more search-efficient than any simple design to check if one line is in the other file.  Likewise, if youre on *nix, the diff tool can do this as well.

Comment: If you're on a *nix platform, I would recommend using the batch for doing this (you can call a bash command from python), something like diff --suppress-common-lines -y <(sort file1) <(sort file2)

Comment: A useful sort of order-of-magnitude calculation: a character is one byte, a line is (say) 75 characters, so reading the entire file into memory would take round about `600000 * 75 / 1000000 = 45MB`. That's trivial these days, so you can just read both files into memory and compare them that way. Of course, if you were working with significantly larger files then you couldn't do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be pretty fast:

```
with open("a.txt") as a:
    with open("b.txt") as b:
        with open("c.txt", "w") as c:
            c.write("".join(set(a) - set(b)))
```

Note that this will disregard any order that was in A or B. If you absolutely need to keep the order from A you can use this:

```
with open("a.txt") as a:
    with open("b.txt") as b:
        with open("c.txt", "w") as c:
            b_lines = set(b)
            c.write("".join(line for line in a if not line in b_lines))
```

Comment: nice. +1. I think this should be accepted as the official answer, unless the ordering of `c` needs to be the same as `a`...

Comment: @nightcracker: Thanks a lot, this is indeed lightning fast! Cheers!

Comment: @Shane: if my answer solved your problem consider marking it accepted by clicking the tickbox to the left of my answer.

Comment: Why not doing it in a more flexible way, not requiring you to store two large files in the memory, along with three large sets (two made from files, one being the difference between them)? Plus you could use context manager instead of explicitly closing files (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Comment: @Tadeck, you old timer, grab your 8G of memory while it's cheap!  It's only going to get cheaper.  IOW, being a memory hog (especially for one-off scripts) isn't as bad as it used to be.

Comment: @Tadeck: because memory is cheap, and my time is not. I wrote this in 30 seconds and according to the OP it is lightning fast. Why bother? And I don't like using context managers in simple examples like these because these questions are often asked by new programmers that will only get confused by it.

Comment: @nightcracker: I get your point. If it works, then it works. I was concerned with the amount of memory it consumes, as the execution times sum up to something more, hmm... expensive. Context managers may confuse, but they do right things at the same time (they close files even though newbie programmers may not). But leave it as is (simply because it works and OP did not ask for more). I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you hold B in memory? If so, read file B and create an index with all the lines it contains. Then read A line by line and check for each line whether it appears in your index or not.

```
with open("B") as f:
    B = set(f.readlines())

with open("A") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line not in B:
           print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about python, but: how about sorting the file A into a particular order? Then you can go through file B line by line and do a binary search - more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Read in all lines in file B into a `set`:

```
blines = set(file_b)
for line in file_a:
    if not line in blines:
       append_to_file_c
```

600k+ is not really that much data...

Comment: No need for a list comprehension, the file is a line by line generator. so you can call `set(file_b)`

Comment: @jamylak, right, unless you want to keep the ordering: Lines in C ordered the same as in A, except missing lines also found in B.

Comment: no matter how you construct the set it will not preserve order.

Comment: @jamylak, precisely! that is why i iterate over A. This maintains the ordering in C wrt A.

Comment: I was just referring to the creating of the set `blines`. If you you pass it a list comprehension it has to load that into memory first but if you pass it a generator it creates the set line by line which is more efficient.